# Combining sections of a polyline in QGIS whilst summing a attribute table column

Tags: qgis, vector, geoprocessing

ive got to condense a sewer layer from junctions (small sections of pipe between manholes)to one section of pipe between the manholes and sum the lengths of all the sub sections.

Does anyone know of a way to do this in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply dissolve by either connectivity or sewer id (whatever is most appropriate in your use-case).

Length is a 'natural' attribute of line geometry and is accessible by using the field calculator to extract this value to an attribute (open the field calculator and you'll see it if you expand 'Geometry' in the middle pane).